# artifact:mvn ant task fails with maven 3.3.x

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm using ant version 1.9.6 and maven 3.3.9.
The following ant task fails with maven 3.3.9. It works perfectly well with maven 3.2.5.

```
<artifact:mvn pom="modules/pom.xml" mavenHome="${env.MAVEN_HOME}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="install" />
</artifact:mvn>
```

The error message is: `[artifact:mvn] -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.`

I've managed to find a workaround (and would like to share it with you):

```
<artifact:mvn pom="modules/pom.xml" mavenHome="${env.MAVEN_HOME}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <jvmarg value="-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory" />
    <arg value="install" />
</artifact:mvn>
```

As you can see it, adding a jvmarg element to set the maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property (without any specified value) solves the issue.

**Questions**: what is this system property about? I did not specify any value for this system property, should I? (in order to take advantage of some new feature in maven 3.3.x)

Comment: Why using Ant Task and not Maven directly ? Are you calling the `mvn install` from a child module?

Comment: We are using an ant task for historical reasons. We have a huge ant project that calls maven, and are in the process of replacing progressively ant by maven.

Comment: First using the workaround you have found will continue building but is not the real solution cause the variable is used to define the root of your multi-module build structure. Within this root folder you can define `.mvn/` folder which can contain configuration for maven as well as for the jvm and you can place extensions there...So the variable should not only being defined it should also provided a real value to it...The variable is defined in the [`mvn` script itself](https://goo.gl/2VZz2k).